# Citrix - Always prompt for user Credentials only on a particular delivery group

Tags: citrix, citrix-receiver

In our environment we have a Delivery group say: "Test Group", where users use their test account to login through their store front and the as SSO is enabled, they just click on the machine and login to it.  The problem is that most of the users are not Tech Savvy and whenever they need to login to Test, they first need to logout of their "Prod" account from StoreFront and then go through the process of logging in with their "Test" account".  This causes a lot of grief to them and want it changed.

I was thinking of showing the "Test Group" when they login with their "Prod" account but when they start the machine, have the machine prompt with for the Credentials, wherein they put their "Test" account.

We cannot remove SSO on "Prod" SF as it would impact other delivery groups
How can I make is so that the machines in that specific delivery group always prompt for Credentials?